# Синхронные смещения слоев внутри соседних контейнеров на чистом css

Tags: css

Есть верстка:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 500px
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: yellow;
  border: green 1px solid;
}

.container a {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">

    <h3>Заголовок<br>1<br>1<br>1</h3>

    <div><a href="">Иван Петров</a></div>

  </div>

  <div class="item">

    <h3>Заголовок</h3>

    <div>
      <a href="">Иван Петров</a>
      <a href="">Иван Иванов</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Ниже картинка, которая показывает что я хочу добиться.

[image]

Мне необходимо, чтобы при увеличении высоты заголовка в одном из контейнеров (и как следствие, смещение его автора ниже), авторы, которые находятся в соседних контейнерах были на одном уровне с этим самым низким по расположению автором. Т.е. все авторы в соседних контейнерах должны равняться на уровень самого низкого. При этом, если самый "низкий" автор - двойной (тройной), то остальные авторы находятся на одном уровне с первым в списке. Как это реализовать на чистом css? grid? куда копать не могу никак разобраться. Можно разбить конечно на строки таблицы, но тогда не получится законченная текстовая целостность контентного блока, все данные будут разнесены по разным строкам таблицы, чего не хочется

UPDATE

вот такое решение я смог сотворить, но если небольшое "но" - при попытке переноса двух последних контейнеров под первый и второй (изменение ширины браузера, применяется новый @media запрос) все сбивается в кучу - получается каша

```css
.container
{display: flex; width: 800px; flex-wrap: nowrap}

.container .item
{display: flex; width: 25%; max-width: 25%; flex-direction: column; position: relative}

.container h3
{background: gray; margin: 0; padding: 0; flex-grow: 1;}

.container .bottom
{position: absolute; bottom: -1px; left: 0; height: 1px; width: 100%}

.container .meta
{background: #ed91ee; min-height: 60px; width: 100%}

.container a
{display: block}
```

```html
<div class="container">


    <div class="item">
        <h3>
            Заголовок 1
        </h3>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="meta">
                <a href="">Иван Петров1</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <h3>
            Заголовок 2<br>2<br />2<br />2<br />2<br />
        </h3>

        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="meta">
                <a href="">Иван Петров2</a>
                <a href="">Иван Петров2</a>
                <a href="">Иван Петров2</a>
                <a href="">Иван Петров2</a>
                <a href="">Иван Петров2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="item">
        <h3>
            Заголовок 3
        </h3>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="meta">
                <a href="">Иван Петров3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <h3>
            Заголовок 4
        </h3>
        <div class="bottom">
            <div class="meta">
                <a href="">Иван Петров4</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разметку не менял (хотя стоило бы 2 элемента выкинуть):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto auto / 1fr auto 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background: yellow;
  /* grid-column-gap: 1px; */
}

.item {
  display: contents;
}

.container::before {
  content: "";
  border-left: inherit;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
}

.container a {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="item">

    <h3>Заголовок<br>1<br>1<br>1</h3>

    <div><a href="">Иван Петров</a></div>

  </div>

  <div class="item">

    <h3>Заголовок</h3>

    <div>
      <a href="">Иван Петров</a>
      <a href="">Иван Иванов</a>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: О, спасибо! Классное решение! Да, я там не все вычистил, когда листинг примера формировал. Я позже выложу еще более простое решение, там с ордером флекс айтема замес получился, но тоже неплохо вышло. Спасибо за вариант!

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov, да, через строчный флекс тоже можно, но там надо будет аналогично от обёртки избавиться, а из минусов - порядок нарушается.

Answer (score 0):

Вы так хотели?

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.wrapper__items {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 10px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.item:not(:last-child) {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="wrapper__items">

    <div class="item">
      <h2>Произведение</h2>
      <h2>Автор</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <p>Просто делай, делай просто!</p>
      <p>Оскар Хартман</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <p>Богатый папа, бедный папа</p>
      <p>Роберт Кийосаки</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <p>Жизнь без целей</p>
      <p>Стивен Шепира</p>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <p>Алхимик</p>
      <p>Пауло Коэльо</p>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: нет, запустите пожалуйста мой код. там видно все

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov ничего не понимаю

Comment: ну оставьте тогда, подождем других

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov я думаю вам нужно более понятно объяснить просто

Comment: Честно говоря, я не знаю как более понятнее объяснить, Я пошагово и подробно описал задачу. С добавленной ниже в html картинкой-иллюстрацией (может вы ее не увидели?) можно сказать доразжевал...UPD подкрасил бэк и бордер у контейнеров дочерних, на всякий случай,  может так понятнее будет + картинка

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .item-wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.container .item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-wrap">
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Заголовок<br>1<br>1<br>1</h3>
      <div><a href="">Иван Петров</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="item-wrap">
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Заголовок</h3>
      <div>
        <a href="">Иван Петров</a>
        <a href="">Иван Иванов</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: интересное решение, спасибо. небольшой нюанс: если делаю `<a>` автора блоком (ну т.е. авторы друг на другом, в столбик) - то слой с авторами начинает расти вверх - а вот как бы его заставить ВНИЗ увеличивать высоту?

Comment: @IlyaBazhinov, сделать фиксированную высоту (или минимальную высоту) у элемента выше, в вашем случае у `h3`

Comment: не представляется возможным, h3 (заголовок) вещь динамическая, он рулит высотой а все остальное должно под него подстраиваться. Поэтому и ушел от фиксированных величин

Comment: посмотрите пожалуйста - я там апдейт выложил, он на полную ширину - то что надо, но при переносе части флекс айтемов на новую строку (изменение ширины браузера) - все сбивается в кашу (не удивительно - если отчасти используется абсолютное позиционирование). Может Вам какая идея в голову придет?

Comment: тут надо поймать правильный @media при уменьшении ширины браузера - но что то никак он не ловится